# Submitting a form from the preview page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that I've been working on for a project. On it, there are a couple buttons, one that resets it, one that submits it, and one that previews the submission. The preview button opens up a separate php page on top of the form using this:

```
<a class="preview" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="preview.php" id="reset">Click to preview submission</a>
```

And the submit button (on the original page) submits the page and sends the data to the server using:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="saved" name="saved" onClick="return showConfirm();"  />
```

However, I cannot seem to get the preview page to have a functioning submit button. I'm wondering if there's a way on the preview page to do that? The button on the preview page that closes the preview page and returns to the main page is this:

```
<p align="right">
<span id="reset">Click Here To Close Page</span></p>
```

Opening and closing the preview page doesn't affect the data in the original form.

Answer (score 0):

If I uderstood.

You should store your variables in a sesseion.

Check this tutorial will help you:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: I don't understand how that will allow me to create a submit button on my preview page.

Comment: You store a variables and put in hidden fields. and the form will only display the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure if I understood you, but I'll try to answer...

There is a easier way to do this. What you can do is put the `preview.php` page inside an **`<iframe>`** on the page that has the form, **but NOT showing yet**. So, when a person clicks on the `preview button`, it makes a preview editing the `preview.php` page (Basically, I think it was what you did) and call it to show on the iframe (you can do it with javascript). So, you don't need to modify the `submit button` and stuff.

I don't know if you could understand me, but it's not a very tricky idea.

***Sorry for my bad english.***

Comment: There isn't a submit button on the preview page though, that's what I'm trying to add.

Comment: But the submit button stays on the form page, not in the preview page. In the same page we'll have the form, the `iframe` I said and the `submit button`.